# Forest package: Left-align all nodes on every level

Tags: align, tikz-trees, trees, forest

The tree below looks exactly the way it should. But is a more elegant way to left align all nodes on every level without explicitly specifying `tier` on every node? This is error-prone and really clutters up the source. Is there a global option I can maybe put in the `for tree`-propagator?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, anchor=west}
[Root, 
  [C1, for children={tier=1} 
    [GC1Long, for children={tier=2} [GGC1][GGC2]]
    [GC2, for children={tier=2} [GGC1][GGC2Long]]
  ] 
  [C2Long, for children={tier=1}
    [GC1, for children={tier=2} [GGC1][GGC2]]
    [GC2]
  ]
  [C3VeryLong, for children={tier=1}
    [GC1][GC2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would something like this work? This is based on the example on pages 45-46 of `forest`'s manual.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={grow'=east, child anchor=west, anchor=base
      west, tier/.pgfmath=level()}
    [Root,
    [C1
    [GC1Long [GGC1][GGC2]]
    [GC2 [GGC1][GGC2Long]]
    ]
    [C2Long,
    [GC1 [GGC1][GGC2]]
    [GC2]
    ]
    [C3VeryLong
    [GC1][GC2]
    ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>forest</code> tree with more complex set up and less complex node specifications]

Comment: Thanks so much! `forest` indeed has a very nice manual.